# how to release a class object which is manually retained

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, ios4

I am working on a Tab Bar based application
I have a class A with its .xib and a class B with its .xib

On class A i am loading multiple instances of class B.

i.e In class A ,i am doing.

in .m file

```
   -(void)renderData:(NSArray *)Data
    {
         for(int i=0;i<[Data count];i++)
            {
               B *grid=[[B alloc]initWithNibName:@"Beta" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
               .
               .
               . //do something with the grid object i.e assign new image etc..)
               [self.myGrid addObject:grid]; //i have a NSMutableArray myGrid declared in .h
               [grid release];  
            }
    }
```

now in the myGrid Array i have all the objects of the grid saved.

Now i am adding them to the class Aplha view.

```
    for(int i=0;i<[myGrid count];i++)
      {
        B *grid1=[[myGrid objectAtIndex:i]retain]; //i have done this retain because when i try to come back to this tab or try to call the same function it crashes by saying message send to deallocated instance.
        [self.view addSubview:grid1.view];
       }
```

now my problem is that how to release the grid1 object that i have retained.

Comment: You can call release method on this object in the same iteration and it simply decrease the count of retain. What's problem you are facing?

Comment: i tried to release it also but when i tried to load that view with some new data it tells me that the message send to deallocated instance

Comment: Should `[beta alloc]` be `[B alloc]`

Comment: its [B alloc] forgot to edit that..:P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are approaching this wrong. The problem here isn't how to release the `grid1` object, it's why you are retaining them in the first place. You most likely shouldn't be; you need to investigate the original crash more thoroughly.

If your `grid1` objects are stored in `self.myGrid` then they are retained by that array. Are you releasing `myGrid` anywhere? As long as that is retained, your `grid1` objects should be.

In addition, there are some conceptual issues here. Loading a view controller from a nib and adding it's view as a sub-view of another view controller's view is generally not correct. It's hard to recommend the correct approach without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve though.

You do not need to pass in `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to `initWithNibName:bundle:` - you can simply pass in nil as the default behaviour is to use the main bundle.

Your comment says you have "assigned" an `NSMutableArray` in your header. You don't assign anything in your header, you just declare things. Have you actually initialised the `NSMutableArray` somewhere in your implementation?

Comment: ya sorry for that, i have declared it in .h and i am initializing it in a function which is called by viewDidAppear. and i am releasing the myGrid in dealloc function. but ater loading the class B on class A there are certain operation i want to perform like when i tap on the grid(class B view) it shows a popOver in which we can see the data in the grid in a bigger size. and many other function.

Answer (score 2):

- You own any object you create when

> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”,
>   “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or
>   mutableCopy).

- When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an
  object you own

> You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message
>   or an autorelease message. In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing
>   ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as
>   “releasing” an object.

To release **grid1** use `[grid1 release];`

---

Note: There is no reason to retain/release your grid1 object in cycle. Just

```
B *grid1 = (B*)[myGrid objectAtIndex:i];
[self.view addSubview:grid1.view];
```

I don't know what happened with your rest code but it looks like you have some memory leaks in another place.

Comment: ya i have memory leaks too but whenever i tried to solve the leaks( like release the object when their task is over) the app crashes.